MongoDB Delete old data
We want to clear our Mongo of old records (older than 90 days), we have a replica set with 3 nodes and we have 3.8 terabytes of data (in /var/lib/mongodb) on each node
We want to clear old records using this way

db.Clicks.deleteMany({ “callData.path”: “/info-dubai”, “callData.date”: { $lt: new Date(new Date().getTime() - (86400000 * 90)) } } );

db.Clicks.deleteMany({ “callData.path”: "/info-qatar, “callData.date”: { $lt: new Date(new Date().getTime() - (86400000 * 90)) } }) ;

And after completing these two requests, disk space is not freed up, and i have to run the command for compaction

db.runCommand( { compact: ‘Clicks’ } );

After compaction, the space is freed up, but the cleaning itself takes a very long time and loads I/O quite heavily, and compaction itself also affects performance, please tell me, maybe there is a way to do this more productively? faster and with less load

Do you need the freed space for something else? In documentation it says "This command is useful if you have removed a large amount of data from the collection, and do not plan to replace it." I think in 90 days it will be used again.

That Q is more suitable to dba.stackexchange.com, I would say.

Have you considered using the TTL index?
The manual does not recommend it due to unmanaged writes, but if yours doesn't have load problems it might come in handy
